# filter as attributes that selected by client?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, attributes, sequelize.js

I use postgresql/sequelize and findAndCountAll function. I want client can filter based on attributes that choose , I haven't any idea to this , if you have any solution let me know.
this is my code:

```
try {
  const { count, rows: usersPersonalInfo } = await PersonalInfo.findAndCountAll({
    offset: (pageNo - 1) * pageSize,
    limit: pageSize,
    subQuery: false,
    distinct: true,
    where: {
       userId: { [Op.in]: allowedOrgUserIds }, 
       deletedAt: null,
  },
  attributes:["firstName", "middleName", "lastName", "dob"],
    include: [
      {
        model: User,
        attributes:["id", "user"],
        include:[
          {
            model: Location,
            as:'locations',
             attributes:["id", "locationName", "locationAddress"]
          }, 
      ],
      }]
  })
  success(res)({
    providersList: usersPersonalInfo,
    total: count,
    pageNo,
    pageSize,
  })
} catch (error) {
handleError(res)(error);
}
```

for example I want see only firstName , dob , and locationName attributes .

```
127.0.0.1:10000/attributesFilter/pageNo=1&pageSize=10&sortBy=&sortASC=&attributes=dob,firstName
```